# Alamofire OSX Upload Video

Tags: swift, macos, video, alamofire

Trying to be able to upload short video files using Alamofire. The api is an API Gateway endpoint that points to a lambda function which processes the video and then stores it in S3. I just need to figure out why I cant get the videos off of the mac sent to the API correctly.

```
func uploadVideo() {
    let buildUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToVideoFile)

    Alamofire.upload(buildUrl, to: apiUrl).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue with the default upload process that I was attempting. My video files were larger than maximum payload size of 10MB that AWS API Gateway supports so I was able to create a work around by requesting a pre-signed url for AWS S3 and then posting the video directly to S3

```
func getPresignedUrl() {
    let uploadUrl = URL(string: awsLambdaUrl)

    Alamofire.request(uploadUrl!, method: .put, parameters: ["filename": filename ], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        if let result = response.result.value {
            let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
            self.postToS3(JSON["url"] as! String)
        }
    }
}

func postToS3(_ url: String) {
    let buildUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0], isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("\(filename).mp4")
    Alamofire.upload(buildUrl, to: url, method: .put, headers: ["Content-Type": "video/mp4", "x-amz-acl": "public-read"]).responseString { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            return self.deleteVideo()
        }
    }
}
```

And the AWS Lambda function that handles the pre-signed urls is:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var params = {
        Bucket: 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME', 
        Key: `${event.body.filename}.mp4`, 
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Expires: 120,
        ContentType: 'video/mp4'
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, { url });
        }
    });
};
```